# How to get Code from Contract Acccount?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, golang

I have a piece of code that connects to the network and displays transaction data.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Whoops something went wrong!", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    tx, pending, _ := conn.TransactionByHash(ctx, common.HexToHash("0x30999361906753dbf60f39b32d3c8fadeb07d2c0f1188a32ba1849daac0385a8"))
    if !pending {
        fmt.Println(tx)
    }

}
```

I would like to get a code from a contract account , how can i get it by modifying this code, with only the address of this account.

I try do it

```
conn.CodeAt(address)
```

but the `CodeAt` method needs more parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://godoc.org/github.com/obscuren/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client.CodeAt:

> `func (ec *Client) CodeAt(ctx context.Context, account common.Address,
>   blockNumber *big.Int) ([]byte, error)`
>
> `CodeAt` returns the contract code
>   of the given account. The block number can be `nil`, in which case the
>   code is taken from the latest known block.

So, e.g.:

```
conn.CodeAt(context.Background(), address, nil);
```